# Assign register value to TYPO3 CASE key

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

Am making some complex menus and would like to use CASE (or similar) to determine the number of submenus in a given branch in order to determine the style of menu to use.

Code:

```
5 = HMENU
5 {
    entryLevel = -1

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1

        NO = 1
        NO {
           ...
        }

        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB {

            10 = CASE
            10 {
                key.data = {register:count_menuItems}

                1 = COA
                1 {
                    data = {field:title}
                    data.insertData = 1
                }

                2 = COA
                2 {
                    data = {field:title}
                    data.insertData = 1
                }

                default = COA
                default {
                    data = {field:title}
                    data.insertData = 1
                }
            }

            wrapItemAndSub = |
        }
    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        maxItems = 2
        expAll = 1
    ...
    }
}
```

How can I get CASE to work? I've tried it with and without the braces.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the MenuProcessor? With output in Fluid it's far easier to handle that kind of complexity.

Comment: a `COA` with a `data`property will not render (wrong syntax). you might mean `TEXT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get more information how to access fields, register and other data in typoscript.

if you have a property you mostly can modify the way to get other information than a constant text.

In your example it is the `key` property where constants are not meaningful.

if you want to access a field of the 'current' record/data you just use `key.field = fieldname`

if it is other data you modify it to `key.data = register:registername`
accessing a field can be done with `key.data = field:fieldname`

If you want these data connected to other information you could use a wrap:

```
key.data = register:registername
key.wrap = prefix- | -suffix
```

Notice: the parts of the wrap are trimmed before they are connected

another way would be an inline notation where you even can use multiple values:

```
key = {register:registername}-with-{field:fieldname}
key.insertData = 1
```

here you have two replacements. each has to be wrapped in braces `{}` and you need to tell TYPO3 that there are replacements to do: `insertData = 1`

---

special case `TEXT`object:

```
10 = TEXT
10.value = constant Text

20 = TEXT
20.field = fieldname

30 = TEXT
30.data = register:registername

40 = TEXT
40.value = register is '{register:registername}' and field is '{field:fieldname}'
40.insertData = 1
```

---

ADDED:

[see the manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/DataTypes/Index.html#gettext) of the typoscript data type `getText` where you can find what else can be used instead of `register`:

then the [manual entry for `data`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#data) which is a property of the function `.stdWrap` and of type `getText`.
This entry is followed by the property `field` stating, it is a shortcut for `data = field:`
(This explaines why your `COA` with `.data` results in anything, as doing a `.stdWrap.data` on any object will replace the object's content.)

be aware that `field` (either as property or as key of `getText`) will select

- a field of the current record, which might vary dependent on context:
- for page rendering it is the record of the current page (table `pages`),
- for rendering a content element it is the element (table `tt_content`),
- inside a filesProcessor it is a file (table `sys_file`_reference`),
- in the `renderObj` of `CONTENT`, `RECORDS`, or `split` it is the selction  you define.

Comment: I did all that and nothing came off of it. I also came across a lot  of similar examples on the internet but from previous years (there were no postings on the subject for the past one year). For example, segment 30 in your example above will work only if you add 30.data.insertData = 1 and use braces. segment 40 will work. Segment 20 will work only inside a menu or content object otherwise fieldname will have to be preprended with 'field:' text. Will upvote your answer coz you may have a different experience than mine. TYPO3 10 documentation doesn't say anything about these changes.

Comment: some more explaination in my answer

Comment: Thanks Bernd. Would you be so kind as to help with this other question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957586/typo3-produce-images-in-different-sizes

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. As far as I can tell, `CASE` works on `stdwrap.cObjects` and so the code

```
10 = CASE
10 {
   key.data = {register:count_menuItems}
   ...
}
```

should be

```
stdWrap.cObject  = CASE
stdWrap.cObject {
   key.data = register:count_menuItems
   if.isTrue.data = register:count_menuItems
   ...
}
```

This way it works.

Comment: it's not the `cObject` (which should not be added to `.stdWrap`) but the notation with/without braces

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I did try with/without the braces and still didn't work. I even tried cObject alone (without stdwrap) and still didn't work. Maybe it's different for TYPO3 V10+?